# computer is locked after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade

I recently upgraded from the 14.xx version to the latest 15.04, and when I tried to wake up my computer after entering the sleep mode during install, it was not accepting my password. After a few unsuccessful attempts, the screen has entered into an inactive state where it is just displaying a screensaver with the current date/time. I am not even able to get the login prompt. I am on HP Evny 700 desktop.
   What can the problem be? I read about a wring keyboard layout being selected, so , if this is the case, is there any way I can change this from the state my machine is at currently? or anything else?
   Thanks for the help,
   Sid.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the keyboard layout from the login screen using the button on the top right of the screen.
It's the en_US button on the picture below.
If this doesn't work or it isn't there we will try finding out which layout you are currently using.

[image: The en_US button on this picture]
There is also a way to change the keyboard layout using a live disk (if you haven't encrypted your hard drive). But lets first try the button on the top right.